# Unstack DF with duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm new to pandas, I have a data set which I would like to change the exposition of it.

[image: Data set]

It has 40.000 rows and 13 columns, and it has the financial information of 2010 ('Último') and of 2009 ('PENÚLTIMO')

The part that interests me is: 'NOME' (Name of the companny),'GRUPO_DFP' (For now it is only the balance sheet but I plan to add more), 'ORDEM_EXER'(Current or last year, 2010 or 2009), 'DS_CONTA' (type of asset), 'VL_CONTA' (the value)

This is all public information, by the way.

So, dropping the columns that I don't want, I get this:

[image: Data set, dropped columns]

Here starts the problem.

It show the info like a normal csv:

```
ORDEM_EXER-----DS_CONTA-------------------------VL_CONTA
PENÚLTIMO-----Ativo Total-----------------------702571987.0
ÚLTIMO--------Ativo Total-----------------------802819794.0
PENÚLTIMO-----Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa-----31037881.0
ÚLTIMO--------Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa-----25219700.0
```

But what I want is:

```
                  ÚLTIMO      PENÚLTIMO
 DS_CONTA
Ativo Total ----802819794.0--702571987.0
Caixa e Eq..----25219700.0---31037881.0
```

After many tries I got this:

```
DF = DF.set_index(['NOME', 'GRUPO_DFP', 'DS_CONTA','ORDEM_EXER'], append=True)
DF.unstack()
```

[image: result]

Still, it's not how I intended.
Trying to skip the first line and just unstacking, returns an error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

So, I'm really clueless of what I could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframe like yours:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['PENÚLTIMO','Ativo Total','702571987.0'],
                  ['ÚLTIMO','Ativo Total','802819794.0'],
                  ['PENÚLTIMO','Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa','31037881.0'],
                  ['ÚLTIMO','Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa','25219700.0']], columns=['ORDEM_EXER','DS_CONTA','VL_CONTA'])
```

represent this:

```
    ORDEM_EXER--DS_CONTA-----------------------VL_CONTA
0   PENÚLTIMO---Ativo Total--------------------702571987.0
1   ÚLTIMO------Ativo Total--------------------802819794.0
2   PENÚLTIMO---Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa--31037881.0
3   ÚLTIMO------Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa--25219700.0
```

Try to use pivot:

```
df.pivot(index='DS_CONTA',columns='ORDEM_EXER',values='VL_CONTA')
```

represent this:

```
ORDEM_EXER-----PENÚLTIMO---------------------ÚLTIMO
DS_CONTA        
Ativo Total--------------------702571987.0---802819794.0
Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa--31037881.0----25219700.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I understand correctly, you really want to set index just for **DS_CONTA**

```
DF = DF.set_index(['DS_CONTA'])
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to achieve pivot values of a pandas dataframe.
If the dataframe is:

```py
df
>>>
ORDEM_EXER  DS_CONTA    VL_CONTA
0   PENÚLTIMO   Ativo Total 702571987
1   ÚLTIMO  Ativo Total 802819794
2   PENÚLTIMO   Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa   31037881
3   ÚLTIMO  Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa   25219700
```

Then

```py
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='VL_CONTA', index=['DS_CONTA'], columns=['ORDEM_EXER'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, we create a data frame, with your sample data:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''ORDEM_EXER-----DS_CONTA-------------------------VL_CONTA
PENÚLTIMO-----Ativo Total-----------------------702571987.0
ÚLTIMO--------Ativo Total-----------------------802819794.0
PENÚLTIMO-----Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa-----31037881.0
ÚLTIMO--------Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa-----25219700.0
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='-+', engine='python')

print(df)

  ORDEM_EXER                       DS_CONTA     VL_CONTA
0  PENÚLTIMO                    Ativo Total  702571987.0
1     ÚLTIMO                    Ativo Total  802819794.0
2  PENÚLTIMO  Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa   31037881.0
3     ÚLTIMO  Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa   25219700.0
```

Now we use a pivot table to reformat and summarize:

```
print(df.pivot_table(index='DS_CONTA',
                     columns='ORDEM_EXER',
                     values='VL_CONTA',
                     aggfunc=sum,
                     fill_value=0))


ORDEM_EXER                     PENÚLTIMO     ÚLTIMO
DS_CONTA                                           
Ativo Total                    702571987  802819794
Caixa e Equivalentes de Caixa   31037881   25219700
```